# Does a sponsored invited talk count for my cv?

Tags: career-path, presentation, medicine

I was invited to give a presentation in a lunch symposium of an important national medical conference. The symposium was sponsored by a pharmaceutical company (my talk was unrelated to their product).

Would this constitute an invited talk in my cv (or keep it a secret)?

Comment: I imagine most conferences and symposia are sponsored by someone or the other, is it not the case in your field?

Comment: The conference was organised by the national society of internal medicine, but they have slots for sponsored content, where there are usually 2 talks about serious subjects and one that may mention a product of said sponsor. This is the case for all national conferences I know and although it would be even better to be an invitee in the main program, this was not bad in my opinion. Just not sure if it would count.

Comment: The company didn't pay *you* right, or recruit *you* specifically?

Answer (score 3):

Normally the sponsorship would be irrelevant to your CV, but in the unlikely case that you were invited by the company instead of the conference, you should specify that in your CV.

My expectation is that the organization of the conference presentations and the sponsorships are completely disconnected.  The sponsorship is simply an opportunity for a company to place their advertisement during the symposium.

Answer (score 1):

You can put anything on your CV that you are proud of and that you think might be useful for someone to know. It is hard for anyone but yourself to really judge that. If it was paid and could be interpreted as a bribe, then it would be problematic, but otherwise probably ok.

So ask yourself, were they just currying favors or did they really want to know what you had to say.

---

Not trying to be insulting, but big pharma has a reputation that isn't the best.